# Dynamic list of integers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, copy-constructor

I'm trying to create a dynamic array in my List class that will start off with a size of 2 and when you insert values with the Insert method, it will check to see if there is enough space if not it will resize the array with a size + 2... The problem is it is crashing VS is complaining about corruption of the heap. Also I think my copy constructor isn't being called because the cout's arent displaying:

list.h File:

```
class List
{
public:

    //  DEFAULT Constructor
    List();
    // Deconstructor to free memory allocated 
    ~List();// Prevent memory leaks

    // COPY Constructor for pointers
    List(const List& value);// copy constructor

    //Modification methods
    void Insert(const int);

    // User ACCESS methods
    void display(void) const;

private:
    int size;// MAX size of the array          
    int count;// current number of elements in the dynamic array

protected:
    int *intptr;// Our int pointer
};
```

list.cpp implementation file:

```
#include "list.h" // Include our Class defintion
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// CONSTRUCTOR
List::List() {
    size = 2; // initial size of array
    count = 0;
    intptr = new int[size]; // Start off 2 integers sized array
}
// DECONSTRUCTOR
List::~List() {
    delete[] intptr; // free allocated memory
}

// Copy constructor

List::List(const List& value) {
    size = value.size;
    cout << "Copy con size : " << size << endl;
    count = value.count;

    cout << "Compy count : " << count << endl;
    if (count < size) {
        intptr = new int[size]; // Allocate new data
    } else {
        intptr = new int[size + 2]; // Allocate new data
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        intptr[index] = value.intptr[index];
    }

    size = size + 2;
    delete[] intptr;
    intptr = value.intptr;
}

void List::Insert(const int value) {
    // do we have room?
    if (count < size) {
        intptr[count] = value;
    } else { // if not we need to add more elements to array
        intptr[count] = value; // DEEP copy invoked with copy constructor
    }

    cout << "SIZE: " << size << endl;
    cout << "COUNT" << count << endl;
    count++; // Increase items added in array
}

void List::display() const {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        cout << intptr[i] << endl;
}
```

main.cpp tester

```
#include <iostream>
#include "list.h"

int main()
{
    List mylist;

    mylist.Insert(5);
    mylist.Insert(6);
    mylist.Insert(2);
    mylist.Insert(8);
    mylist.Insert(4);
    mylist.Insert(5);
    mylist.Insert(9);
    mylist.Insert(8);
    mylist.Insert(5);
    mylist.Insert(9);
    mylist.Insert(8);
    mylist.Insert(5);
    mylist.Insert(9);
    mylist.Insert(8);
    mylist.Insert(5);
    mylist.Insert(9);

    mylist.display();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does indexing a `int *` and assigning to the result call the copy constructor of your class?

Comment: You claim that a deep copy is being perfomed but there doesn't seem to be any. How are you expecting a copy of your list to be taken? Have you considered just updating the size of the array that you are using instead of relying on the copy constructor?

Comment: Why not use the `std::vector` or `std::list` class instead of writing your own?  Both are dynamically-growing lists. `std::vector is an array, much like your class, whereas `std::list` is a linked-list of tree nodes instead.

Comment: Thought it was automatically invoked?

Comment: Copy constructor would be automatically invoked, if you were ever making a copy.  You are not.  You create one instance and then call insert a bunch of times.  Is this some sort of homework assignment?  I cannot think of why you would want to do this normally, unless perhaps you were trying to control memory better than std::vector does, since it doubles the size each time it needs more...

Comment: @user978563 The code in the `Insert` member function says `if( count < size ) { /* do blah */ } else { /* do blah */ }`. Why would `do blah` meaning anything different in the `else` half?

Comment: I'm just learning how to make a list myself before I use the faster Vector and STL ways

Comment: Clearly you need to learn how pointers and copy constructors work before you take on a collection that attempts to use them.  The fact is, your copy constructor is doing things that are not it's job (trying to increase the size of the array), and it is never even being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not managing the array correctly, especially in your `Insert()` method.  Try this instead:

```
#include "list.h" // Include our Class defintion 
#include <iostream> 

// CONSTRUCTOR 
List::List()  
{ 
    intptr = new int[2];
    size = 2;
    count = 0; 

    std::cout << "Initial size : " << size << " count : " << count << std::endl; 
} 

// DECONSTRUCTOR 
List::~List() 
{ 
    delete [] intptr; // free allocated memory 
} 

// Copy constructor 
List::List(const List& value) 
{ 
    intptr = new int[value.size]; // Allocate new data 
    size = value.size; 
    count = value.count; 

    for(int index = 0; index < count; ++index) 
        intptr[index] = value.intptr[index]; 

    std::cout << "Copy size : " << size << " count : " << count << std::endl; 
} 

void List::Insert(const int value) 
{ 
    if (count == size)
    { 
        int *newintptr = new int[size+2];

        for(int index = 0; index < size; ++index) 
            newintptr[index] = intptr[index]; 

        delete[] intptr;
        intptr = newintptr;
        size += 2;
    }

    intptr[count] = value; 
    ++count;

    std::cout << "New size : " << size << " count : " << count << std::endl; 
} 

void List::display() const 
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        std::cout << intptr[i] << std::endl; 
}
```

.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "list.h" 

int main() 
{ 
    List mylist; 

    mylist.Insert(5); 
    mylist.Insert(6); 
    mylist.Insert(2); 
    mylist.Insert(8); 
    mylist.Insert(4); 
    mylist.Insert(5); 
    mylist.Insert(9); 
    mylist.Insert(8); 
    mylist.Insert(5); 
    mylist.Insert(9); 
    mylist.Insert(8); 
    mylist.Insert(5); 
    mylist.Insert(9); 
    mylist.Insert(8); 
    mylist.Insert(5); 
    mylist.Insert(9); 

    mylist.display(); 
    system("PAUSE"); 

    List mylist2(myList); // copy construct a new list

    mylist2.display(); 
    system("PAUSE"); 

    return 0; 
}
```

With that said, you really should use `std::vector` instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream>            
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void displayValue(int value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl; 
}

int main()            
{            
    std::vector<int> mylist;            

    mylist.push_back(5);            
    mylist.push_back(6);            
    mylist.push_back(2);            
    mylist.push_back(8);            
    mylist.push_back(4);            
    mylist.push_back(5);            
    mylist.push_back(9);            
    mylist.push_back(8);            
    mylist.push_back(5);            
    mylist.push_back(9);            
    mylist.push_back(8);            
    mylist.push_back(5);            
    mylist.push_back(9);            
    mylist.push_back(8);            
    mylist.push_back(5);            
    mylist.push_back(9);            

    std::for_each(mylist.begin(), myList.end(), displayValue);
    system("PAUSE");            

    std::vector<int> myList2(myList);

    std::for_each(mylist2.begin(), myList2.end(), displayValue);
    system("PAUSE");            

    return 0;            
 }
```

To take it a step further, if you want to keep using your custom `List` class, at least use `std::vector` inside of it:

```
#include <vector>

class List  
{  
public:  
    //  DEFAULT Constructor  
    List();  

    //Modification methods  
    void Insert(const int);  

    // User ACCESS methods  
    void display(void) const;  

protected:  
    std::vector<int> intvec;
};
```

.

```
#include "list.h" // Include our Class defintion 
#include <iostream> 

// CONSTRUCTOR 
List::List()  
{ 
    intvec.reserve(2);
    std::cout << "Initial size : " << intvec.capacity() << " count : " << intvec.size() << std::endl; 
} 

// Copy constructor 
List::List(const List& value) 
{ 
    intvec = value.intvec;
    std::cout << "Copy size : " << invec.capacity() << " count : " << intvec.size() << std::endl; 
} 

void List::Insert(const int value) 
{ 
    intvec.push_back(value); 
    std::cout << "New size : " << intvec.capacity() << " count : " << intvec.size() << std::endl; 
} 

void List::display() const 
{ 
    for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = intvec.begin(), end = intvec.end(); iter != end; ++iter) 
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl; 
}
```

.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "list.h" 

int main() 
{ 
    List mylist; 

    mylist.Insert(5); 
    mylist.Insert(6); 
    mylist.Insert(2); 
    mylist.Insert(8); 
    mylist.Insert(4); 
    mylist.Insert(5); 
    mylist.Insert(9); 
    mylist.Insert(8); 
    mylist.Insert(5); 
    mylist.Insert(9); 
    mylist.Insert(8); 
    mylist.Insert(5); 
    mylist.Insert(9); 
    mylist.Insert(8); 
    mylist.Insert(5); 
    mylist.Insert(9); 

    mylist.display(); 
    system("PAUSE"); 

    List mylist2(myList); // copy construct a new list

    mylist2.display(); 
    system("PAUSE"); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Looks like I'm trying to do too much with the copy constructor and it works diff than I thought, thanks I'm studying your code now

Answer (score 8):

Your `List::Insert(const int value)` method doesn't call the `List` copy constructor at all, it only writes inside the `intptr` array. When `count` gets bigger than `size`, you write outside of the array and that's why you have errors.

You should move what you do in the copy constructor to the `Insert` method directly.

Comment: how would the copy constructor be called though, its confusing

Comment: The copy constructor would be called if you ever made a copy of an instance of the object. In other words, if you had two instances of your list, a and b, and said a = b.

Comment: Try adding `List myotherlist(mylist);` in your main and you will see all those `cout`s appear :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for copy-constructor is to create a new object from existing one, but look at you copy-constructor, what are you doing there?

```
/* initialize my size and count, from value */
size = value.size;
count = value.count;

/* Check count and size */
if( count == size ) /* if other is full */
    size += 2;

/* copy content from value.intptr into this->intptr */
//if (count < size)
//    intptr = new int[size]; // Allocate new data
//else
//    intptr = new int[size + 2]; // Allocate new data
intptr = new int[size];  /* Allocate my buffer */

/* It's better to use std::copy in place of a hand written loop */
//for(int index = 0; index < count; index++)
//    intptr[index] = value.intptr[index];
std::copy( value.intptr, value.intptr + value.count, intptr );

/* why you increase your size here?? shouldn't this indicate size of intptr? */
//size = size + 2;

/* After creating a new buffer and putting data into it, you destroy the buffer
   and set your buffer equal to buffer of value? why? if value destroyed it will
   destroy its intptr and your intptr point to a deleted memory
*/
//delete [] intptr;
// intptr = value.intptr;
```

Now look at your `insert` method:

```
if(count < size) // do we have room?
{
    intptr[count] = value;
}
else // if not we need to add more elements to array
{
    /* As you already checked you do not have enough room to insert data to intptr
       so why you do it here? shouldn't you first allocate a new buffer and then
       copy data to it?
       In comment you say DEEP copy with copy-constructor, which copy constructor
       you expect to called here? you are assigning an int to another int, so where
       is copy constructor?
     */
    // intptr[count] = value; // DEEP copy invoked with copy constructor
    int* tmp = new int[size + 2];
    std::copy( intptr, intptr + size, tmp );
    delete[] intptr;
    intptr = tmp;
    size += 2;
    intptr[count] = value;
}

count++; // Increase items added in array
```

Comment: @user978563 No I think you are lucky that you can learn fast :)

Answer (score -1):

Use std::vector. It already does all of this, and does it safer and faster than your code will.