# Infinite size Stack implementation using pointer to an array

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I have been trying to make a infinite size stack using pointer to any int:

```
//in class:
int* stack;

//In constructor:
stack = new int();

//In deconstructor:
delete stack;

//In Push:
stack(++top) = element;
```

Is this declaration correct? Can I use this to make an infinite size stack? I run into error when I try to put elements into the stack using such pointer declaration.

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982730/dynamic-list-of-integers-in-c

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are writing codes in C++? If no, please just ignore my post(face palm).

Firstly, the memory that could be assigned to a program is limited, i.e. no infinite size stack. In C++, there is BSS, Stack and Heap memory. In your case, you have used `new` operator to assign memory. This in fact effectively means you would like to get a piece of memory in the heap to store your value. Though the size of heap could be dynamically extended, its memory size is still not infinite.

Moreover, it seems what you would like to do in the constructor is to build up an int array with unlimited size. In fact, to declare an array, you may write `new int[arraySize]` to declare an int array of size, `arraySize`, in the heap. However, what you have written here is allocating a single int in the heap since the brackets you used are not square, but round. Unfortunately, to create an array, you need to declare its size first (for more details, you may search for stack array and dynamic array). So as to get rid of the size problem, you may use other data structures like `std::vector` and so forth for simple.

```
int* stack;
stack = new int();
```

These 2 statements are to have a pointer pointing to a single int stored in heap memory. Therefore, currently, the stack you make seems to be only able to store an int only.

As for the push function, top is the index of the top int in the stack?

One more thing, in case, what you want to make is creating a pointer to point an int array, and use the array as a stack. Then, you may think about the way to add memory, and have the deconstructor revised to be like this:

```
delete[] stack;
```

If you find difficulty in understanding my above paragraphs and have interest in learning more, perhaps you may firstly learn about stack & heap, then, the array declaration as well as its relationship with the memory allocation, followed by the knowledge about pointers.

I am a newbie. Hopefully, I haven't made any mistake in my answer.

Comment: Yes it is c++. What say makes sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all `new int ()` creates only a single `int` not an array of integers therefore you can't do something like `stack(++top) = element;`.

If you want to create a dynamic array you should use `int* stack = new int[size]` and delete it with `delete [] stack`. As you can see the array has a limited size of `size` but you can resize it when it becomes full. There is no built-in way to resize the array but you can create a new dynamic array with bigger size and copy the old array into it and then remove the old array. But again the stack won't have infinite size since your memory is limited. If the allocation fails an exception will be thrown.

Below is a simple implementation of stack based on a dynamic array.

```
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

class Stack{

public:
    Stack (int _size = 20){
        size = _size;
        topIndex = 0;
        stack = new int [size];
    }

    ~Stack (){
        delete [] stack;
    }


    void resize(){
        int new_size = size*2;
        int * new_stack;
//        try{
        new_stack = new int[new_size];
//        } catch (std::bad_alloc&) {
            // unsuccessful allocation
//        }
        for ( int i=0; i<size; ++i ){
            new_stack[i] = stack[i];
        }
        delete [] stack;
        stack = new_stack;
        size = new_size;
    }


    void push(int element){
        if (topIndex + 1 == size){            
            resize();
        }
        stack[topIndex++] = element;
    }

    int top(){
        if ( topIndex <= 0 ){
            throw std::out_of_range("stack is empty");
        } else {
            return stack[topIndex-1];
        }
    }

    void pop(){
        if ( topIndex <= 0 ){
            throw std::out_of_range("stack is empty");
        } else {
            --topIndex;
        }
    }

private:    
    int * stack;
    int size;
    int topIndex;
};

int main(){
    Stack stk;
    for ( int i=0;i<50;++i ){
        stk.push(i);
        cout << stk.top() << endl;
    }
    for ( int i=0;i<50;++i ){
        stk.pop();
        cout << stk.top() << endl;
    }
}
```

*Note that this is all just for practice and the above implementation is error prone. You should almost always use built-in data structures in practical situations.*

Comment: Thanks I understand it now :)